# Is there a way to merge get parameters? - HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, get, http-get

often I find myself suprized about simple things, I'm not sure but I believe that this might be one of them.

Often I find myself needing to **merge get attributes, especially within filters and search pages within sites.** This come be at times quite complicated, as you might want to remove and add parameters dynamically.

Simple way to do it is to use a form, but this get complicated, when adding elements that don't belong within a form. e.g. pagination

For example I might have a URL such as the following

> http://www.example.org/ninja_search/?speed__gt=5&night_sight=1&page=1

How would I merge such URL with page=2, substituting the 1 with the new value? Is javascript the only option?

> ?speed__gt=5&night_sight=1&**page=1** + **page=2** = ?speed__gt=5&night_sight=1&**page=2**

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `[]` to explicitly create an array from the parameters, providing your server side language supports it:

> ?speed__gt=5&night_sight=1**&page[]=1&page[]=2**

For example, if your server-side language is PHP, `$_GET['page']` will now return an array with 1 as the first element and 2 as the second.

You can use this technique in forms too, by applying it to the `name` attribute:

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="hidden" name="page[]" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="page[]" value="2" />
</form>
```

---

If you're talking about adding a second parameter and ignoring the first, this will happen anyway - the second provided parameter will override the first.  Assuming

> ?speed__gt=5&night_sight=1&page=1&page=2

The value of `page` at the server will be 2, because the last value given takes priority.

Comment: Hi @Andy! Thanks, btw I was thinking more about removing the old page value.

Comment: @RadiantHex: oh, sorry :-) I've added some more info to my answer.

Comment: Ok thank you very much Andy! =) There is no way of literally removing the previous parameter I guess? In any case excellent response, I'm ticking this!